# Cannot SSH to a second computer inside my network

Tags: networking, ssh, router, putty, port-forwarding

I have two Linux servers running right now. The first one works just fine when I try to connect from [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).

- Port 22 is forwarded for my working SSH server.
- Port 911 is forwarded for my not working SSH server

I cannot connect to the second server using the internal IP address or the external IP address. When trying to connect to the internal, I receive this message from PuTTY:

> Network Error: Connection Refused.

When I try using the external IP address it will just time out.

The two server IP addresses and other information are listed below.

**Working server:**
IP: `253.68.xxx.xx:22` <-Port **22** is being forwarded on my router

**Not Working server:**
IP: `192.168.1.222:911` <-Port **911** is being forwarded
or
IP: `253.68.xx.xx:911`

I have looked at several posts by other people with this issue, and I have had mixed advice. Some people have advised editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file while others have advised against it.

Comment: How did you try to connect ? post the command. And yes you need to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change the port to 911, and restart or re-read the ssh server. It is possible your isp is blocking 911, so try 8022 or some such.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am trying to connect via putty. My isp is not block 911, I called them to verify that this port was available.

When I change the /etc/ssh/sshd_config port to listen to port 911, restart the ssh service, and try again I get the following error from putty; "Network Error: Software caused connection abort"

Comment: did you specify port 911 in putty?

Comment: Yes, in the box just to the right of the IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages from /var/log/auth indicate that the installation of ssh did not complete properly.  Host keys do not exist, and without host keys, ssh is unable to initiate user authentication.

You don't mention the flavor of Linux (redhat,debian,gentoo) and each has a different command structure for re-installing the sshd.

My recommendation is to uninstall then re-install the sshd daemon on Linux, then try again.  If you get the host key error again, then perhaps your distro requires you to manually create those keys.  See the readme file for sshd and that should guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure SSH to listen on that port.  Just forwarding the port on the router does not do this.

On the problem machine, change the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to have

```
Port 911
```

Enable passwords for SSH with this setting:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Restart the SSH service so it will take effect.

Comment: I have already made this change and restarted the service, now the error message given by putty reads; "Network Error: Software caused connection abort".

Comment: You can check PuTTY's event log to see how far it got in the process.  On the Linux side, check the logs there for clues.

Comment: This is what my /var/log/auth shows:

Jan  8 17:48:53 Phoenixbox sshd[2091]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Jan  8 17:48:53 Phoenixbox sshd[2091]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Jan  8 17:48:53 Phoenixbox sshd[2091]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Jan  8 17:48:53 Phoenixbox sshd[2091]: fatal: No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]

Comment: Maybe you should change the config to have password auth allowed?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I compared both /etc/ssh/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config from my working SSH server with my non-working SSH server; they are exactly the same except the non-working server has "Port 911" in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config where the working server has "Port 22".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SSH server is listening on port 911 for your non-working server (192.168.1.222:911):

It is likely that the firewall on that machine is blocking any incoming connections on that port (911). To resolve this, you will need update the firewall to allow incoming TCP connections on port 911.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I set the firewall to allow all and I still receive the same error. "Network Error: Software caused connection abort".

Answer (score 0):

I removed the working server from my network and configured the non-working server to listen on port 22 and forwarded the port on the router for this server, it did not make a difference.

After spending a few more hours I found this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/205179/ssh-problem-read-from-socket-failed-connection-reset-by-peer and it helped my resolve the issue with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server openssh-client
```

After reconnecting both servers on my network I can SSH to `68.253.xx.xx:22` and end up at the first server and I can SSH to `68.253.xx.xx:911` and end up at the second server.